# Unable to add using Sonata Admin Form

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Symfony 4 and I have 3 entities in my application - User, Department and Company. A company will have many departments, and a department will have many users.

I have set up Sonata Admin and I am able to edit a user, however if a try to view the add user form, I get the following error:

```
PropertyAccessor requires a graph of objects or arrays to operate on, but it found type "NULL" while trying to traverse path "department.company" at property "company".
```

Here is my UserAdmin:

```
class UserAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('firstName', TextType::class)
        ->add('lastName', TextType::class)
        ->add('department.company', ModelType::class, [
            'class' => Company::class,
            'property' => 'name',
        ])
        ->add('department', ModelType::class, [
            'class' => Department::class,
            'property' => 'name',
        ])
        ->add('email', TextType::class)
    ;
}
```

Comment: ....do you really want to edit the company within an department when opening the edit page for a user? What happens if you remove `department.company` from the field list?

Comment: The form displays fine with department.company removed. Is it possible to display different fields for add / edit views?